# How do I get the ID of a dropdown attribute by its text label?

Tags: attributes, collection-filtering, dropdown-attribute, script

I have a product attribute which is configured to be a dropdown with a fixed list of available values.

Now I need to write a script which will filter based on the selected value of the dropdown attribute.  The filter needs to know the integer ID of the value, but the script input uses the text based label of the attribute.

How would I lookup the integer ID of the desired attribute value?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Selects in magento are normally like this: `<option value="INT_VALUE">STORE_SPECIFIC_TEXT_VALUE</option>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use something like this.

```
 $attribute = Mage::getModel('eav/config')->getAttribute('catalog_product', "your attribute_code");
 $arg_value = "your  text based label";
    foreach ( $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions(true, true) as $option )
    {

        if($arg_value == $option['label'])
        {

            unset($attribute);
            echo $option['value'] ; 
        }
    }
```

This will give you Integer ID of your text based label

Comment: Perfect, that's exactly what I was after

Comment: Sorry, this makes no sense for me: if($arg_value == $option['label']) Because:
You try to get the current label and say if(value1 == value1value2value...) So the "if" is senseless How do I get the current ID of a current Dropdown value?

Comment: The `==` operator is a comparison operator in PHP, it is not an assignment operator (which is a single `=` character). Given that information it should be clear that the `if` is not sensless at all.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a more concise approach to translating a text label into it's value of:

```
// Returns the value ID of the 'example' label for 'some_attribute'
Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getResource()
  ->getAttribute('some_attribute')
  ->getSource()->getOptionId('example');
```

---

Bonus: To convert an integer value to a text label is a little easier:

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
  ->setSomeAttribute(5)
  ->getAttributeText('some_attribute');
```

Both of those examples leverage the `catalog/product` model without actually loading a product. If you're working with a loaded product you can use that instance as well.