# Get Product Attribute Value for Dropdown Without Loading the Whole Product

Tags: attributes, dropdown-attribute

Been using this snippet to retrieve the attribute values but this only works for input type text or boolean but not for dropdown type of attributes:

```
$_resource = Mage::getResourceSingleton('catalog/product');
$_resource->getAttributeRawValue($_productId, 'color', Mage::app()->getStore());
```

For the select dropdown type, it returns bool(false) and I am expecting it would return the dropdown frontend value/label.

How can I get the attribute value of a product without loading the whole product model?

Thank you.

Comment: can you add screenshot what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get the ID of a dropdown attribute by its text label?](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/17780/how-do-i-get-the-id-of-a-dropdown-attribute-by-its-text-label)

Comment: @STW That other answer works but seems kludgy. I'm inclined to leave this open.

Answer (score 3):

Another option for getting dropdown attribute value :

```
$_product->getAttributeText('contrast_ratio');
```

getAttributeText method is use for retrieving the `SELECT`, `MULTISELECT`, `DROPDOWN` or `YES/NO` attributes value.

Comment: it returns only TEXT means not its Value. Like dropdown option 33,34 etc, but it shows AM,PM(which is text)

Answer (score 1):

Below code is help you out :

```
$_product->getResource()->getAttribute('contrast_ratio')
    ->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
```

Note : `contrast_ratio` is your dropdown attribute code

Comment: Well, I don't need to load the whole product model so I don't have access to $_product.