# Script update attribute for all products

Tags: attributes, product-attribute, script

I need to update the attribute value of all products (80.000+). How can I fix this using a script?

The attribute that should be updated is the following:

Attributecode: `eboekhouden_grootboekrekening` 
Attributetype: `dropdown` 
The value that should be selected: `8000 - Omzet Shop`

Is the following code right?

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL);

require('app/Mage.php'); // this is assuming your script is located in the Magento root dir
Mage::app(); // initiate the Magento engine

$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();

foreach($products as $product)
{
    $product->setEboekhoudenGrootboekrekening('8000 - Omzet Shop');
    // this line might not be required - compare results with & without it 
    $product->setEboekhoudenGrootboekrekeningIsFormated(true);
    $product->getResource()->saveAttribute($product, 'eboekhouden_grootboekrekening');
}
?>
```

Comment: provide more information with example.

Comment: @GopalPatel Thanks for your reply. What kind of information do you need?

Comment: What is currently in your system and what you want to achieve

Comment: @GopalPatel Currently there is not a value selected in the dropdown. So I want to select the value `8000 - Omzet Shop` from the dropdown and save it. I added my current code, what I currently have.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: actually I think **the fact that it's a dropdown attribute will cause issues.** You probably want to test that first on a single product to see how it behaves because I'm pretty sure the dropdown attribute values are option ids and not the text values.

Apart from that, your code is definitely correct, however it won't save the second attribute `eboekhouden_grootboekrekening_is_formated`

You'll need to add the following line if you want to save that attribute too:

```
$product->getResource()->saveAttribute($product, 'eboekhouden_grootboekrekening_is_formated');
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Raphael. I already removed the `eboekhouden_grootboekrekening_is_formated` part, that is not needed. But how do I need to edit the value for the dropdown? Do I need to change the text to the option id? So that it will become `$product->setEboekhoudenGrootboekrekening('8000');`

Comment: @HenkZ no I reckon you should use some code to find out what's the option id of this value. SOmething like this: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/17780/how-do-i-get-the-id-of-a-dropdown-attribute-by-its-text-label